# Laravel: CSRF token not needed for login via axios

Tags: laravel, forms, authentication, csrf

When I use a form to post to the /login route, a valid CSRF token is needed.

```xml
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
```

However, I can login completely without the token simply using:

```js
axios.post("/login", { email:this.email, password:this.password })
    .then((res) => {
        window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    })
```

This is a security risk, right? Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: only for routes defined in api.php CSRF-tokens aren't needed since VerifyCsrfToken middleware is not added to api group by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a vulnerability. If you check your `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file, a comment explains this.

> ```js
> /**
>  * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
>  * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
>  * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
>  */
> ```

If you inspect the request made in the network tab of your browser's dev tools, you will see the XSRF-Token header.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it well. You never stop learning.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your frontend.blade.php file head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And in your bootstrap.js file it is
well protected by declaring and authorizing axios.